# I'm translating a play and in the midst of it there is a German sentence I cannot understand

Tags: german-to-english

I don't know German and here is the sentence.

> "Wunderbar! Peter look! Wie die geht! Wie die aussieht, die ist genau meine Kragenweite!" *(Arnold Wesker, Kitchen)*

I used google translate but couldn't understand what he means.
Previously he was talking to a waitress he likes at work and when she answers him, he says this to his friend peter. Is he talking about the way she works? How she looks? How a tie would fit him?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Genau) jemandes Kragenweite sein is a German proverb meaning

> to be to one's taste
>
> to find something/someone likeable/appealing

or

> to be with someone at the same level

Imagine a shirt collar that fits perfectly around your neck (collar size - Kragenweite).

A [similar english proverb](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/suit-sb-right-down-to-the-ground) might be

> suit sb (right) down to the ground

[or](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/my-cup-of-tea.html)

> My cup of tea

In this case, the man is talking about a woman he sees, so you can translate it like this

> "Wonderful! Peter look! The way she walks! The way she looks, she suits me right down to the ground.

Alternative:

> she is exactly what I'm looking for
>
> she is what I'm talking about
>
> she is my cup of tea

**edit:**

From the comments:

> she's just my type

Comment: omg perfect! thanks :)

Comment: I would suggest idiomatically *she's just my type*.